# How to print rows from dataframe between two index numbers

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, rows

#How to print rows from dataframe between two index numbers.

#From the below code last line is not working.

```
index = df.index

condition1= df["main"] == "march"

condition2= df["main"] == "august"

row1 = index[condition1]
row2 = index[condition2]
i = row1.tolist()
j = row2. tolist()
df. iloc[i:j]
```

Comment: @HenryEcker Yep, you're right. Didn't notice `df['main']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused because you are passing `list` `i` and `j` to `iloc`. You can revise it as follows and it should solve your problem.

```py
index = df.index

condition1= df["main"] == "march"

condition2= df["main"] == "august"

row1 = index[condition1]
row2 = index[condition2]

i = row1.tolist()[0]
j = row2. tolist()[0]

df. iloc[i:j]
```